# A word to describe a task becoming "easier but more dangerous"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need to find the right word for a situation I am writing. The idea is that as your score increases, you automatically gain more points on top of this. The goal is to avoid reaching the maximum, but as you increase your score, it becomes easier to accrue these points.

The phrase I currently am using is:

> Embracing becomes easier over time, where it becomes dangerous and risky to try and collect more.

I feel that "easier" is the opposite of what I want, because collecting the points towards your score *is* easier, it's not what you want to do; making it more dangerous as your score increases.

Comment: Blackjack .....

Comment: [_Parrondo's Paradox_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrondo%27s_paradox)

Comment: So—to be clear. If you lose when you have 1,000 points, are you saying that it's easier to go from 500 to 550 points than it is to go from 0 to 50 points? Is point collection *itself* actually easier the more you have—or is it just how easy it is to *lose* because you're closer to the 1,000? (If it's both, there was a *Doctor Who* episode with that principle . . .)

Comment: I don't know a word, per se, but I know an idiom: "slippery slope" (e.g., As you gain more points, the more you step on to a slippery slope to maxing out and losing.).

Comment: @JasonBassford yes, that's it in a nutshell. You lose when you reach 1000, and the closer you are to losing, the easier it is to reach that point.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Yeah. If there isn't a "word", I'd go with a phrase, like that.

Comment: *The closer to the finish you get, the faster you travel toward it.* I'm pretty sure that calculus can be used for that kind of calculation—but I don't know how to express it more succinctly. (And it's not a slippery slope, because that normally involves a steady gradient.)

Comment: @JasonBassford yes precisely, it is calculus, i.e., acceleration

Comment: also the phrase "dangerously easier" could work

Answer (score 1):

I think the concept you are addressing is akin to [**acceleration**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration), i.e., *"In physics, acceleration is the rate of change of velocity of an object with respect to time."* So specifically, positive acceleration. If I'm understanding it correctly, you're talking about, as @Lawrence pointed out, a game of Blackjack — but a very specific game of Blackjack, i.e., one where every card is higher/larger/of greater value than the last (as opposed to "standard" Blackjack, where cards could be bigger or smaller).

One possible rephrasing, below, substitutes 'increase of (rate) increase' and bolds other key terms on which the definition hinges.

> [Accelerating Score]
>
> Your goal is to get the highest score possible without **surpassing** the maximum, or you lose. Note as your score increases, the **rate at which it increases increases**; as you accrue points, you automatically gain **even more** points on top of the points gained.

Answer (score -1):

> Embracing becomes easier over time, where it becomes dangerous and risky to try and collect more.

---

Personally I think it is not a word you need but a total re-write with some poetic license thrown in! Try

**Scoring becomes easier as your tally becomes larger, but annihilation awaits as your score  races towards the brink of oblivion.**

or something similar you could use accelerates instead of races but personally I think most people would get the drift.